# Get database URL from Terraform `azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server`

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm using `azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server` and creating a database. I'm not seeing an output defined though that gives me the url of the database so that I might pass it into a created server as an environment variable and access the database.

How would I get the Database URL after creation?

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/postgresql_flexible_server#attributes-reference says there's a `fqdn` attribute.

Comment: it appears that fqdn is what I needed.  I wasn't aware that FQDN was the access url. Could you submit this as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just want to add on @ceejayoz's answer what is happening under the hood to complete this question with an answer.

To get the database URL from a `azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server` resource in Terraform you can use the attribute fdqn which you add to the respective database URL:

```
fqdn = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.example.fully_qualified_domain_name
```

and pass it to the `db_url`

```
db_url = "postgres://admin:password@${fqdn}/db"
```

May it help others too!